# Maximize log-likelihood of logistic regression

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the equations for the logistic regression. I'm following the cs229 notes:

http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf

At some point in the derivation, in the notes we need to maximize the log-likelihood of the parameters:

ℓ(θ) = log L(θ) = y log h(x) + (1 - y) log(1-h(x))

In the notes, after the derivation we get:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}$ = (y $\frac 1 {h(x)}$ - (1 - y) $\frac 1 {1 - h(x)}$) $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}$h(x)

Shouldn't this be:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}$ = (y $\frac 1 {h(x)}$ + (1 - y) $\frac 1 {1 - h(x)}$) $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}$h(x)

I've been looking at this for a while and I can't see where this minus sign is coming from...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $\frac{\partial \log (1-h(x,\theta))}{\partial\theta}=\frac{1}{1-h(x,\theta)}\frac{\partial (1-h(x, \theta) ) }{\partial\theta}=\frac{1}{1-h(x,\theta)}(-1)\frac{\partial h}{\partial\theta}$. For more details I refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression/477261#477261

Comment: There is a mistake in the different equations in that there is not $\theta$. Do you mean $h(x^\text{T}\theta)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little to explain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \ell(\theta) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}
\left\{  y \log h(x) + (1 - y) \log(1-h(x)) \right\}\\
&= y \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \log h(x) + (1 - y) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \log(1-h(x))\\
&= y \frac{1}{h(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} h(x) + (1 - y) \frac{-1}{1-h(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} h(x)\\
&= \left( \frac{y}{h(x)}-\frac{1-y}{1-h(x)} \right) \frac{\partial h(x)}{\partial \theta_j}
\end{align*}
So it is because
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\log(1-x) = \frac{-1}{1-x}$$ that you get this expression.